# (WPF DataGrid) How to copy Datagrid header text with a context menu?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, columnheader

I'm using WPF  DataGrid.

I added a context menu to the column header, but i don't know how can I copy the header text in a menu item click event.

I try to use DataGrid.CurrentColumn but it is null

Thanks a lot !

Comment: you need to copy the selected column with its header?

Comment: i want to copy the header text only .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to get columns header by get it using the selected cells:

```
foreach (var item in e.SelectedCells)
{
    DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item.Item);
    var col = item.Column as DataGridColumn;
    MessageBox.Show("" + col.Header);
}
```

**EDIT**
if you want to get the column header that you are currently on add the following codes:

in resource put this:

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="cm">
            <MenuItem Header="Click"
                                  Click="mi_Click" 
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Parent}" />
        </ContextMenu>
```

then add column header style like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource cm}"></Setter>
</Style>
```

and put code behind like this:

```
private void mi_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MenuItem mi = sender as MenuItem;
    if (mi != null)
    {
        ContextMenu cm = mi.CommandParameter as ContextMenu;
        if (cm != null)
        {
            var ch = cm.PlacementTarget as System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridColumnHeader;
            if (ch != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ch.Content.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it shows the column header correspond to the cell i had selected , but not the column I right click mouse in